# BLOB aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I've got the table:

```
create table example (id number, image varchar2(10));
```

With 2 rows:

```
insert into example (24, 'pippo');
insert into example (35,'pluto');
```

The query is:

```
select max(case when id=24 then image end) as col1,
       max(case when id=35 then image end) as col2
from example;
```

This works perfectly fine with column "image" as varchar2! The problem is that the column is a BLOB.

How can I produce the same output?

Take in mind that I need to pull out of the table 28 images (so 28 columns and one row).

Comment: Is ID unique? If so you could use 28 subquery expressions, I suppose. But who/what will call this and consume the results - does it really need them as columns rather than rows? And will the number of images (andthus columns) vary?

Comment: So, what kind of data is stored in the BLOB columns? If it is text (very long perhaps), why is it BLOB and not CLOB? And if it should be CLOB, can you fix that first?

Comment: Many thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name for editing the question. I didn't noticed that was written in a bad way.

Comment: @AlexPoole the id is unique BUT i can't do 28 subquery.. It will become poorely performant. Also, i need 28 column, not rows. Yes, maybe in the future the number of images/columns could vary

Comment: @mathguy in  the BLOB columns there are images.

Answer (score 0):

Still not clear why you need the result in columns and not rows... perhaps you only think you do? Alex asked you the most important question: Who/what will call this and consume the results? How is the result set used in further processing? It is possible you don't actually need the results in columns.

In any case, you can use Alex's suggestion of having 28 subquery expressions. If your concern is with performance, you can first select into a CTE (a WITH clause), whose result set will have just 28 rows - and then write the subquery expressions against the CTE. Something like this:

```
with prep ( id, blob_col ) as (
       select id, blob_col from base_table where id in (24, 35, ... )
     )
select
  (select blob_col from prep where id = 24) as col_1,
  (select blob_col from prep where id = 35) as col_2,
  ...
from dual
;
```

Comment: It has to be used by a web application that take the name of the column and the value (the image) and substitute it in a docx document where there are tags identified by the columns' names (so i need a one to one corrispondence column-value). Why do you say that these 28 query don't affect performance? I thought that 28 calls to the same table were expencive...

Comment: 28 calls to a very large table are very expensive. The solution reads your very large base table only once, to create the CTE (inline view, subquery, whatever you want to call it). The 28 calls are only to this subquery, whose result set has just 28 rows. 28 calls to an inline view with just 28 rows aren't expensive at all.

Comment: The reason for "columns" is still not clear. The web application is not written properly; the 1-1 correspondence exists just fine in a table where the correspondence is in rows. But if that means modifying the application... I'm not going to get into it.

Comment: neither do i.. i don't know java or any other language.. I'm trying to make things simple: they tell me that they need a value for each "tag" (aka a specific string in the docx). There are 900 tag so i'm trying to group them and interrogate the database the less possible (they wanted to do a query for each tag!!) but i'm crashing into BLOB type and it's quite difficult to interact with...